# Use WixUIBannerBmp in my custom dialog

Tags: wix

In my installer I have set WixUIBannerBmp to point to my own custom `dialog-banner.bmp`.
Now I have added a custom dialog I would like to have the same banner as on the other dialogs.

Is there a way to refer to the existing WixUIBannerBmp?

Workaround would be to create a Binary containing the image and refer to that. But it seems like it shouldn't be needed.

/L

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you just need to use this in your dialog definition:

```
<Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44"
    TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)"/>
```

When I need to create a custom dialog, I just copy one of the standard dialogs from the wix sources and adapt it to my needs. These controls all have the above line, and I've never had to do anything extra to keep the banners in my custom dialogs the same as for the rest.